# Disabling internal keyboard

Tags: keyboard

I am trying to get input from my internal keyboard, however, it is not showing the internal keyboard and ID.   (I am using Ubuntu 21.04)

I get the following:

```
WARNING: running xinput against an Xwayland server. See the xinput man page for details.
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:17                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:17              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:17                      id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Can anyone help with fixing this issue, and also advise why `xinput -list` is not showing all details.

Comment: What's the laptop in question? Have you checked the manufacturer's documentation or support pages for answer?

Comment: Your post was difficult to understand.  I've rewritten it - but please check as I may have changed the meaning.

Comment: @Peregrino69 OP said Ubuntu **21** which is not a thing. As its September 2021, 21.10 has not been released.  It is certainly possible I misunderstood the question - hence my comment -   I  expect that English is not the OPs first language and he was trying to enable his internal keyboard  - I could not find an alternative interpretation that made sense in context of his description.

Comment: The OP also started by saying "Im trying to get input from my internal keyboard" - the opposite of disabling it.  He then goes on to ask how to get the keypresses from it. Again,  the opposite of disabling jt.

Answer (score 0):

The tool itself points you in the right direction:

> WARNING: running `xinput` against an Xwayland server. See the `xinput` man page for details.

The relevant details from the man page ([`man xinput`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hirsute/man1/xinput.1.html), emphasis mine):

> Xwayland  is  an  X  server  that  uses a Wayland Compositor as backend.  Xwayland acts as translation layer between the X protocol and the Wayland protocol but does not have direct access  to  the  hardware. **The  X Input Extension devices created by Xwayland (`xwayland-pointer`, `xwayland-keyboard`, etc.) map to the Wayland protocol devices, not to  physical devices.**
>
> These  X Input Extension devices are only visible to other X clients connected to the same Xwayland process. Changing properties on Xwayland devices only  affects  the  behavior  of those  clients. For example, disabling an Xwayland device with `xinput` does not disable the device in Wayland-native applications. Other changes may not have any effect at all.
>
> In most instances, using `xinput` with an Xwayland device is indicative of a bug in a  shell script  and  `xinput`  will  print  a  warning. **Use the Wayland Compositor's native device configuration methods instead.**

I'm not familiar with Wayland and I don't exactly know "the Wayland Compositor's native device configuration methods", but I found this: [*What is the Wayland equivalent of `xinput list`?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/426944/108618)

I believe [you can still use ye olde good X instead of Wayland](https://askubuntu.com/q/1334715/693277) (in fact I'm using it in Kubuntu 21.04 right now). In X `xinput list` should work as you expected.

Comment: The link for the man page is broken, Arch Linux have a working man with this quote: https://man.archlinux.org/man/extra/xorg-xinput/xinput.1.en#XWAYLAND

Answer (score 0):

For users with xwayland, first find the event id.

```
$ libinput list-devices
```

If needed install the libinput (sudo apt install libinput-tools). This will listdonw all the input devices and its event id. Scroll to find the right section (Something like "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard") and find the line Kernel: /dev/input/event#. Use the event# for the next command:

```
$ udevadm info -a -p /sys/class/input/event#
```

Find an attribute that is most probably unique/distinct. For example ATTRS{name}=="AT Translated Set 2 keyboard" and then create rule file

> sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/99-disable_touchscreen.rules

with following rule

```
KERNEL=="event*", ATTRS{name}=="AT Translated Set 2 keyboard", ENV{LIBINPUT_IGNORE_DEVICE}="1"
```

Then check if it worked by following command:

```
$ udevadm test /sys/class/input/event#
```

and search for

> LIBINPUT_IGNORE_DEVICE=1

most probably within the last 3 lines. Then reboot and your intenral keyboard should be disabled.

Courtesy: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Dell_XPS_13_(9343)#Disable_the_touchscreen